# Spring pointcut involving ignoring a class

Tags: spring, pointcut

I have a  point cut for all classes in Spring AOP like

@Pointcut("execution(* com.company.app..*(..))")

Now I need to exclude a class say com.company.app.IgnoreClass.
Can someone please help me write the pointcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pointcut to exclude all methods in `IgnoreClass` would be:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.company.app..*(..)) && !execution(* com.company.app.IgnoreClass.*(..)) ")
```

Documentation about pointcuts expression [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#pointcuts), also more related information on Spring AOP declaring pointcuts [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts).

Comment: In case of XML, this expression would be `"execution(* com.company.app..*(..)) &amp;&amp; !execution(* com.company.app.IgnoreClass.*(..)) "`